# Swift: Accessing outlet in action handler gives "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, swift

Inside my ViewController, I have two `UITextFields`, hooked up as outlets via the storyboard / IB:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
```

I have hooked up an action for "Editing Changed" for one UITextField:

```
@IBAction func textField1Change(_ sender: UITextField) {
    textField2.text = "Changed"
}
```

However, I get a `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error when I type something into `textField1`

I can't even do `print(textField)`, that gives me the error too. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  **textField1** is probably connected to some other action? Check the outlets of the  **textField1** to make sure.

Or try this way :

```
 func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      textField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    }

 func textFieldDidChange(_ textfield: UITextField) {
      textField2.text = "Changed"
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, I just hit this.  Created an action instead of an outlet, then deleted action and created outlet.  Storyboard remembers though